# Convertible Bond Pricer papers

Tags: option-pricing, equities, reference-request, convertible-bond

I'm looking to build a convertible bond pricer. Where should I get started? Which papers/books should I look at?

Comment: Is this a thesis project, academic project, or professional project?

Comment: @BrianB Academic

Answer (score 1):

[Barclays technical introduction to Convertibles](http://www.johnchukwuma.com/training/Convertible%20Bonds,%20A%20technical%20introduction,%20Barclays%20Capital.pdf) is a very good start.

Comment: Updated Link: http://johnchukwuma.com/training/Convertible%20Bonds,%20A%20technical%20introduction,%20Barclays%20Capital.pdf